# Overwriting Environment Variable in CMake

Tags: cmake, environment-variables

I want to overwrite "qt's" environment variable in my CMakeLists.txt if 64 bit architecture is detected. 
How can I do that? 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`set`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/set.html) to replace the value of an environment variable, and a common way to detect 64-bit architecture is to use [`CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/variable/CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P.html).

So, e.g. to append `/x64` or `/x86` onto the environment variable `QtEnvVar`, you'd do:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
project(EnvVarSetter)

message(STATUS "CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P:  ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}")
message(STATUS "QtEnvVar before:      $ENV{QtEnvVar}")
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  set(ENV{QtEnvVar} "$ENV{QtEnvVar}/x64")
elseif(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
  set(ENV{QtEnvVar} "$ENV{QtEnvVar}/x86")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unknown void* size.")
endif()
message(STATUS "QtEnvVar after:       $ENV{QtEnvVar}")
```

Comment: I already have QtEnvVar declared in my computer to point to "c:/Qt". Then, I have two sub directories in it, "x86" and "x64". So, I would like to update QtEnvVar to c:/Qt/x64 if 64 bit architecture is detected or c:/Qt/x86 if 32 bit architecture. So, I tried what you suggested, but it doesn't seem to overwrite QtEnvVar

Comment: @Sunny I've updated my answer to be a bit more specific to your use-case.  If this still doesn't help, you're probably best to show us an example CMakeLists.txt where you have the issue.